# Is charge without mass possible?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, charge

The minimum amount of charge possible is that of quarks. But it also has mass. Why is there no charge without mass? Or is it there?

Comment: *The minimum amount of charge possible is that of quarks* - Well, I would say that the minimum amount of charge possible is that of electrons ([$e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge)), because quarks are not free particles.

Comment: Gluons are massless and they carry color charge.